# What is the file extension when creating Binary files

Tags: c#

I am just trying to learn to write to Binary files. When we create text files we normally give the extension .txt. The same way, what should be the file extension for Binary files created using C#.

Which are the contexts that demands us to write to a binary file. What is the benefit in writing/creating a binary file rather than a text file when processing data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely anything you want, or even nothing at all.

Just make sure you're consistent, and it helps not to use an extension already in wide use such as .doc or .pdf

Microsoft once advised using long extensions of the form `.company-program-format` [1] since you can have extensions longer than 3 characters now, but this never took off to gain wide acceptance in the industry.

1: Footnote: I cannot find a source for this claim but I remember reading it on MSDN around the time Windows Vista came out. You see it in Windows OS files like `dvr-ms`. These former guidelines are alluded to in this page, but the it's link is now broken and points to a totally different page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/cc144156(v=vs.85).aspx#short_and_long

Comment: Could anyone add a little more? Which are the contexts that demands us to write to a binary file. What is the benefit in writing/creating a binary file rather than a text file when processing data. @Dai

Comment: @Unnikrishnan binary files are much faster to read and write because there's no conversion to/from human-readable data (e.g. converting 4-byte integers to one-byte-per-digit base 10 text). If you use memory-mapped files with cast structs (not really possible in C#/.NET but often used in C/C++) then it's even faster because it skips the "reading a file" process.

Comment: @Dai What's the difference between .NET 4.0  [implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) and pure C/C++? Is it just due to the way .NET works, or the underlying Win32 call differ from standar lib in C?

Comment: @Martheen In .NET you still need to use `Marshal` which means copying data between the native and managed worlds, or using `unsafe` code which may be undesirable. Hypothetically `unsafe` C# with memory-mapped files should be as fast as C/C++ though.

Comment: Mr.Dai's comment throws further light on the topic. I just learnt how to write and read integer values.  Would you clarify a further why there is no WriteLine concept when writing to binary files. @Dai

Comment: @Unnikrishnan Because the concept of a "line" applies only to human-readable text. Binary files are typically (but not always) compact and succinct serializations of some data structure. You can always write a line-break if you want to (`0x0D 0x0A`) assuming your program would read it as ASCII or UTF-8 encoded text, such as if you're storing human-readable text within your binary file format.

Comment: I appreciate the answer of Dai to my doubt on WriteLine(). In a simple programme, I almost learned to write strings, int, bool, and double to a binary file. I notice that strings appear as text itself in the binary file. Is the file fast enought as already explained in one of the comments. @Dai

Answer (score 12):

From my experience, **.BIN** and **.DAT** are the most popular extensions for "raw" binary file formats.

But it's just a general convention, you are not limited to follow it in your own projects.

Answer (score 4):

The three letter extension is an important convention for determining file type. While there are many different kinds of binary files represented by extensions such as ".png", ".mov", or ".mp3", for a generic, no-special-meaning binary file such as you are looking for the customary extension would be ".bin".

Answer (score 3):

There is no extension however if you use .BIN then almost everyone will assume you mean binary and that the file should be viewed within a hex editor

If the binary file contains a proprietary format then give the extension more meaning, eg if it should be opened with something other than a hex editor name it as such.

Comment: That sounds good enough as an additional explanation which I had not thought of. Okay.